# Using shared database scripts in flyway

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, groovy, flyway

I have a number of projects written in Groovy using Spring-Boot / Gradle. All of these applications do a similar job for a different client but share a significant amount of functionality.

In order to avoid code duplication I have separated out the shared components into a library and of course this works fine for the Groovy code. However, the library also contains the Flyway scripts to create the schema that the library relies on.

Due to data segregation rules and in order to keep the applications completely separate each app needs to have has its own copy of the database tables in its own schema, and each app has its own database connections details in its own application.yaml.

What I can't then work out is how I can use the shared Flyway scripts in the separate project builds.

I can see one way to achieve this is to run the library's Flyway migrate multiple times (once per app) each time against the appropriate database, but that would involve putting the database details of all the apps into the library - which is again duplication.

I can see another way to achieve this is to put the Flyway scripts in the app projects, but that would involve copying the scripts from the library so rather than having one copy I would have n copies. This would make it painful to change (if I want to apply the change to all or many of the projects) and also ties the application to the database schema definition which is supposed to be hidden by the library.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue? Am I missing anything obvious? Or am I just asking something of Flyway that it can't do?

Thanks

Comment: I may be misreading, but wouldn't the library be it's own JAR, such that you can import it into other projects? Then, you would call a method such as SchemaUtil.migrate() within each application.

Comment: You haven't said if this is a single multi-module build or multiple builds. If a single multi-module build one project can access another project's `configuration`s. If separate builds you'll likely need to publish/consume artifacts (jars) containing the sql files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your common class files and flyway scripts in the same `.jar` file? If this is true then you won't want the jar on your buildscript classpath so I suggest extracting the scripts to a folder and looking up from the filesystem.

eg:

```
buildscript {
    classpath 'my.db:driver:1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'groovy'
configurations {
    flywayScripts { traisitive = false }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.foo:common:1.0' // assuming you also want to compile against common classes
    flywayScripts 'com.foo:common:1.0'
}
task extractFlywayScripts(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(configurations.flywayScripts.singleFile).matching {
        include 'path/to/migration/scripts/*.xml'
    }
    into "$buildDir/flywayScripts"
}

// wire the extraction task into the DAG
flywayMigrate.dependsOn extractFlywayScripts

flyway {
    def yamlConfig = parseYaml('path/to/application.yaml') // TODO: implement parseYaml(...)
    locations = ["filesystem:$buildDir/flywayScripts", "filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration"]
    url = yamlConfig.url
    user = yamlConfig.user
    password = yamlConfig.password

    // etc        
}
```

Comment: My Flyway scripts are sql scripts not Java so they aren't in the jar. Is that a good thing to do? I guess that would involve changing the library build script to include the sql scripts in the jar - but that doesn't feel right (not to say its the wrong thing to do though)

Comment: By default, Gradle (and Maven) will pack everything in `src/main/resources` inside the jar. It's common practice to have non-java resources in a jar including xml, sql, yaml, images etc etc.

Comment: My common class files and flyway scripts are now in the same .jar file. I then used locations = "classpath:..../db" and this works just as I hoped. Reading your post you are suggesting a different approach and I don't quite understand the reasoning behind... "you won't want the jar on your buildscript classpath" can you explain why?

Comment: Having the classes on the buildscript classpath and on the compile classpath feels dirty to me. I wasn't sure if there would be classloading issues